# RXJS: TypeError: this._subscribe is not a function

Tags: angular, ionic3, rxjs5

I'm migrating an ionic 3.8 app to 3.9.2.
This migration includes an update to RXJS 5.5

I'm now experiencing this error:

`TypeError: this._subscribe is not a function. (In 'this._subscribe(sink)', 'this._subscribe' is an instance of t)`

After hours of debugging, I found out that this code portion is related to the error:

```
protected observeConnectionState() {

    // rxjs/observable/of
    of(new Event('disconnect'))
        .pipe(
            // rxjs/operators/merge
            merge(connect$),
            merge(disconnect$),

            // Map eventname to string (rxjs/operators/map)
            map((e: IEvent) => {
                return e.eventName == 'connect' ? 'connected' : 'disconnected';
            })
        )
        // Apply to class context
        .subscribe((newConnectionState) => {
            // this.connectionState$ is a BehaviorSubject
            this.connectionState$.next(newConnectionState);
        });
}
```

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

- There are two places in the RXJS code, were I was able to find `this._subscribe`: [Observable.ts Line 203](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/ad143f15bfe4d2780448f3841d09ccf3db087122/src/Observable.ts#L218) and [Observable.ts Line 208](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/ad143f15bfe4d2780448f3841d09ccf3db087122/src/Observable.ts#L218).

Comment: Can you create an [mcve] that anyone can run without having to try to stub the various variables/fields (like connect$, disconnect$, etc)? Once you have that I would recommend you post this on the [rxjs project](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues) site.

Comment: I'm already working on that. But since that error only occurs in connection with Cordova, I expect these guys to point at Cordova. Cordova will point at them and so on.

Comment: Yeah, that might happen :/. The only other thing you can do, once you have the [mcve], is to copy the entire stack trace with error message to include.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I found the problem. And it's not related to Cordova.

For other people encountering this problem:
Forget the stack trace - it's useless. In my case in a subscriber of `this.connectionState$` I tried to create an Observable from a promise. But I did it wrong.

This is what was wrong:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
//...
const myObservable$ = Observable.create(myPromise);
```

This is how it should be done:

```
import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise';
// ...
const myObservable$ = fromPromise(myPromise);
```

Answer (score 8):

I was getting exactly same error message in one of my angular application while doing upgrade when I replaced `Observable.of(someval as any)` with `new Observable(someval as any)`.

Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this._subscribe is not a function

I also tried to make it `Observable.create(someval as any)` but the same error.

#### Solution

Replacing it with `of(someval as any)` resolved the problem for me.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

// use it just like this
of(retval as any);
```

detailed error message

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this._subscribe is not
>   a function TypeError: this._subscribe is not a function
>       at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe
>   (Observable.js:42)
>       at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe
>   (Observable.js:28)
>       at MapOperator.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapOperator.call
>   (map.js:18)
>       at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe
>   (Observable.js:23)
>       at MapOperator.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapOperator.call